# Bootstrap displaying duplicate elecments in Laravel 8.4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Disclaimer: Newbie

Trying to use Bootstrap via CDN link in header (link to minified bootstrap online). Bootstrap does not seem to be implemented on my blade file.

I'm following this tutorial with uses Laravel 5.2.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhv250daKKg

I should mention, there was initially an issue with the routes, he created /app/Http/routes.php, but my local was ok with using the default /routes/web.php, the page is rendering so I guess that's ok?!

Any help very much appreciated.

Attached is header in master-blade, script in master-blade, the blade file in question (index.blade) and the rendered page.

Please see attached and thank you sincerely in advance. Cheers ~

[image: header]

[image: script]

[image: blade file]

[image: rendered page]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Laravel version doesn't matches with his. Clearly, his code uses Bootstrap 3 and you are using bootstrap 5. Some components do change and the changes between 3 and 5 are huge for some components.

Why are you using that old tutorial? Laravel 8.x is out. Checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFh0Fd7BsjE&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) course if you wanna build Laravel app from the latest version.

If you wanna make a clone of shopping cart and follow his tutorial word-by-word, start a new project with the following command. This will make a new Laravel project of 5.2 version (any desired version infact).

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.2.*" myApp
```

And use bootstrap 3 from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/).